# I'm using webrtc with nodejs socket. I'm facing noise problem, my voice coming back to me

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, audio, webrtc

Clone this project and i'm using webrtc with nodejs socket. I'm facing noise problem, my voice coming back to me.
Complete code on github - https://github.com/coding-with-chaim/toggle-cam-final

If anyone facing same issue. then please provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video you are attaching the stream to,

```
<video autoplay id="user-video" class="user-video"></video>
```

is not muted, hence the voice is played back. Setting the `muted` attribute is the easiest way to avoid that:

```
<video autoplay id="user-video" class="user-video" muted></video>
```